# Remove duplicate rows ignoring column order? in R

Tags: r, duplicates

Hi apologies if this has been asked before, I couldn't find an answer to my question but I've been unsure on the best way to word this - so that might have hindered my searches!

So my data was originally in a matrix like this:

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 0.576 | 0.987 |
| b | 0.576 | 0 | 0.034 |
| c | 0.987 | 0.034 | 0 |

I converted this to long format using melt, and removed the zero values where a value would map to itself, so the data now looks like this:

| var1 | var2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 0.576 |
| b | a | 0.576 |
| a | c | 0.987 |
| c | a | 0.987 |
| b | c | 0.034 |
| c | b | 0.034 |

What's the best way to remove the duplicate rows so that the data would look like:

| var1 | var2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 0.576 |
| a | c | 0.987 |
| b | c | 0.034 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(
    var1 = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "c"), 
    var2 = c("b", "a", "c", "a", "c", "b"), 
    value = c(0.576, 0.576, 0.987, 0.987, 0.034, 0.034)
)
```

A one-liner `base-r` solution:

```
df_unique <- df[!duplicated(apply(df[,1:2], 1, function(row) paste(sort(row), collapse=""))),]

df_unique
  var1 var2 value
1    a    b 0.576
3    a    c 0.987
5    b    c 0.034
```

What it does: work across the first 2 columns row-wise (`apply` with `MARGIN = 1`), `sort` (alphabetically) the content, `paste` into a single string, remove all indices where the string has already occurred before (`!duplicated`).

Another (probably better) approach, stepping back, is to take your original matrix and clear out the bottom half using `lower.tri`. This way only half of the combinations will have non-0 values:

```
mat <- matrix(c(0, 0.576, 0.987, 0.576, 0, 0.034, 0.987, 0.034, 0), 
              nrow=3, dimnames=list(letters[1:3], letters[1:3]))

mat[lower.tri(mat, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
mat
   a     b     c
a NA 0.576 0.987
b NA    NA 0.034
c NA    NA    NA
```